Why is the SPEI::Penman function giving an subscript out of bounds error?
I have a set of data to calculate Potential EvapoTranspiration (PET) using functions from the SPEI package. The Hargreaves function has worked perfectly but the Penman keeps giving "Error in Tmean[2, , ] : subscript out of bounds". Tmean isn't requested in the documentation, I include Tmax and Tmin as stated. Running a value for Tmean included just gives the same error.
Reproducible code:
U2 <- 1.7 #m/s (average)
Ra <- 2.23 #MJ/day (average)
RH <- 89.65 #% (average)
lat <- 52.76624
Tmax <- 14.3 #(degrees C)
Tmin <- 6.9 #(degrees C)


penman<-penman(Tmin, Tmax, U2, Ra, lat, RH, z = 59, crop='short', na.rm = TRUE)

I've had to state the z value in the code because for some reason calling it from a datafile kept giving an error. The rest of the variables are stated values in R studio.
My desired output is one figure attributed to penman which will tell me the PET value for the month I'm calculating.
For the SPEI package to run correctly you will need to load other dependencies:
‘colorspace’, ‘RcppArmadillo’, ‘elliptic’, ‘contfrac’, ‘deSolve’, ‘farver’, ‘labeling’, ‘munsell’, ‘RColorBrewer’, ‘viridisLite’, ‘goftest’, ‘Lmoments’, ‘hypergeo’, ‘plyr’, ‘gtable’, ‘isoband’, ‘scales’, ‘withr’, ‘backports’, ‘generics’, ‘timechange’, ‘lmomco’, ‘lmom’, ‘TLMoments’, ‘reshape’, ‘ggplot2’, ‘checkmate’, ‘zoo’, ‘lubridate’

I don't know if this is needed but I'm running R Studio 2023.12.1 and R 4.3.2
I have imported an excel file with my data and then created individual datafiles in R studio to call on for each variable in the function. This should be pretty straight forward and I can't see what is going wrong. The other function in SPEI has worked fine for me.
Any help appreciated.
UPDATE:
This is now solved thanks to Felix. You need to have a dataset of at least three months' worth for the algorithm to work. My life is now complete.

I'm not familiar with the subject, but I noticed that the 6th parameter of penman() is named Rs according to the documentation. From your example, did you mean to set RH instead? (it throws a different error, but maybe it helps)

Thanks @FelixJassler you can have either or neither. Having one (Ra or Rs) makes it a bit more accurate. As you say though, it doesn't solve the error switching it to Ra rather than Rs. Oh conundrums.

One more uneducated guess, maybe the functions expects a vector of values of length ≥ 3. When I do penman(rep(Tmin, 3), rep(Tmax, 3), rep(U2, 3), rep(Ra, 3), lat, rep(RH, 3), z = 59, crop='short', na.rm = TRUE) it seems to work. If that is the case, I'd have to say that it should be documented better.

@FelixJassler I'd really like to buy you a beer...what you said was completely right. I've just run all my data and it's worked perfectly. I really wish the error message was more explicit! Thanks again!
